# IIS connections overload and CPU running high

Tags: javascript, c#, iis, cpu-usage

We have an MVC 5 website hosted by iis on our server but we are experiencing the following problem with one of the functionalities in the website.

We have a datatable that gets populated with data from a SQL database. For each record a checkbox gets created for users to check and link that record. Once the record is checked and linked, that specific record is stored in a link table. Please see the code bellow for this functionality. For each record I call a method on the server side and that executes the stored proc.

javascript

```
$("#btnLinkTest").click(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var checked_checkboxCounter = 0;
    $('#counter').text("0 linked");
    $('#linkModal').modal('show');

    var oTable = $("#StudentListTable").dataTable();
    $(".cbxLink:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
        checked_checkboxCounter = checked_checkboxCounter + 1;
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        var data = $('#StudentListTable').DataTable().row(currentRow).data();

        var ER, AC;
        var StudentID = data['StudentID'];
        var TestID = $('#lblGradeID').html();
        var ET = $(this).closest('tr').find(".extraTime").val();

        if ($(this).closest('tr').find(".cbxER").is(':checked')) {
            ER = "True";
        } else {
            ER = "False";
        }


        if ($(this).closest('tr').find(".cbxAC").is(':checked')) {
            AC = "True";
        } else {
            AC = "False";
        }

        var jsObject =
        {
            StudentID: StudentID,
            TestID: TestID,
            ModifiedBy: "1",
            ElectronicReader: ER,
            Accomodation: AC,
            StudentExtraTime: ET

        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Administration/LinkTestToStudent_Ins/",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsObject),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                counter = counter + 1;
                $('#counter').text(counter + " / " + checked_checkboxCounter );
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

c#

```
public string LinkTestToStudent_Ins(string StudentID, string TestID, string ModifiedBy, string ElectronicReader, string Accomodation, string StudentExtraTime)
{

    string result;
    DataBaseConnection dbConn = new DataBaseConnection();
    using (SqlConnection con = dbConn.SqlConn())
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StudentTestLink_ins", con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", StudentID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestID", TestID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return result = "Linked";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Connection Error";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if we link over a 100 records for example, the connections on the server goes up a lot (so 100 in this case) and the cpu runs at almost 100% because of the IIS Worker. I suspect that this is happening because the javascript code calls the c# all at once for all checked records.

Please advise how I can optimize this code so that I do not get the above mentioned problem. Possibly I can call the c# method one at a time and not all at once.

Comment: Having  a separate ajax request for each checkbox is going to be slow,  Imo, send all the data in one request and do the looping server side.

Comment: Would the best approach for that be to store it in a array and pass it to the server side?

Comment: Code review is probably the least effective way to troubleshoot such, when live data can easily point out what might be wrong, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

Comment: Before Ajax was a thing, you’d just submit the whole form at once to the server.  You can easily do the same thing with ajax, look at JQuery’s serialize function.  https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: When we troubleshooting high CPU issue, we also need to know which thread is running all the time and what the thread was doing. We would know how to fix this only when we know which method cause the high CPU.  You can enable debug diagnostic tool to check this.